# Jquery only working in window.onload=function()

Tags: google-chrome, angular-fullstack

I'm using the angular-fullstack yeoman generator in my project.

It contains Jquery by default.

`<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` is correctly inside the index.html

Curiously, in my js file, Jquery works perfectly inside this:

```
window.onload=function() {
  //my jquery code working here
    }
```

But, it doesn't work at all if I put in this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // my code is not working here :(
});
```

And from there, I'm getting some trouble. When I switch from a page to an another one, Jquery stopped. I need to refresh the page to keep Jquery working.

I might not have this problem if my Jquery code was inside `$(document).ready(function()`

As I'm using angular-fullstack generator which already makes almost every thing in my project, I don't know where I need to make some change to make it works ..

Any suggestion ? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know using jQuery with AngularJS is not a good practice. Generally if in your angular project you need to use jQuery it means you have to create a custom directive to have some logic there or less ideal alternative is to use `angular.element` which comes with jQuery lite features.

Regarding your problem please test if this will work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // example $('.btn').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I just realize that jQuery is not a grood practice in such project using Angular. So it means I need to "rewrite" everything using angular, not jQuery. My bad.. ^^